# Get list of accounts with last know info

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to achieve following on SQL Server.
On a weekly basis I'll be reading accounts from a database.
On 1/07/2018 I have read 5 accounts with their corresponding color.
A week later I only read 2 accounts because only 2 accounts have changed since then (accountno 10001 and 10004).
Another week later again I only read 2 accounts (10004 and 10005)

As a result I want to achieve the right side.
For each run I want to view the states of the different accounts.
Since I only re-insert changed data (and thus discard records which didn't changed compared to last time) I need to make sure that the unchanged records are also present in the result by search for the last known state of that accountno.

In the end I need a table a table with 15 records (5 accounts for 3 different dates)
Could anyone help me with this, because I can't get my head around this one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) window function to just get the last entry for each account:

```
SELECT accountno, color, datemod
FROM   (SELECT accountno, color, datemod,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountno ORDER BY datemod DESC) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks man, your comment helped me to it.
`SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM (SELECT accountno, color, dateStart, dateEnd,
   ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY accountno ORDER by dateEnd desc) as rn
  FROM #account) t

SELECT TimeDate, DayofWeek, temp.accountNo, temp.color
FROM dbo.dim_time as t
LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp as temp
ON t.TimeDate between temp.dateStart and temp.dateEnd
WHERE TimeKey LIKE '201807%'
--AND DayofWeek = 'Sunday'
AND TimeDate <= GETDATE()`